# What information do I store for a partial event update in Event Sourcing?

Tags: event-sourcing

I have the following data for an existing topic event.

```
id: 123
version: 1
data: { name: "Bob", age: 21 }
topic: 'candidate'
action: 'create'
```

Now I would like to visualise an update to this record. e.g. If the candidate has now been rejected.

Would I add the new event, by spreading / including the previous event data?

```
id: 123
version: 2,
data: { name: "Bob", age: 21, rejected: true }
topic: 'candidate'
action: 'update'
```

or would I record this as a stand alone entry?

```
id: 123
version: 2,
data: { rejected: true }
topic: 'candidate'
action: 'update'
```

or should I do something completely different?

Comment: Seems like option 2 is the way to go from what I have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you want the event to solely be "what changed".  So from that perspective, the second one is better than the first.

But the principle can be applied even further.  What changed is that the candidate was rejected, and that can be defined by a constant string like "rejected" as the event's data/payload:

```
id: 123
version: 2
data: 'rejected'
topic: 'candidate'
action: 'update'
```